# Send HTTP Post data from django view

Tags: django

I have been adding functionality to a django application.

Part of this involves a search/update data page to simplify modifying data and moving it out of the admin interface to improve ease of use.

The workflow is as follows: The user enters a search term. A list of hits are shown with a links to modify/update. The user clicks on a link to make a change and is presented with a form. At the bottom of the page they can click submit or cancel, either of which would take them back to the search page.

So here is my question: how can I redirect the user back to the search page and pass in the original post data?

Thanks!

Comment: Ended up with a simple solution: For my cancel button I am simply using <a href="javascript:history.back()"> For the submit button I am returning to the search page.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the admin does this very thing.

When your user does a search, the urls of the items in the search results should include the search term in the query string. For example, in the admin, each item will have a query string like `?_changelist_filters=q%3Dterm` (i.e. `q=term`). Passing this query at each step in the process is how your application will "remember" the original query.

So when the user clicks on the item, create an `action` url on your form that also includes this query string. Then when the form is submitted, you can redirect back to your search page by using the search terms that are in the query string.

I hope that makes sense. It's hard to be more specific without seeing some actual code.

Comment: I have used this method to pass data between pages, but in this case I have a view method that has both a get and a post method (i.e. if request.method == 'POST' # Do search stuff else # Show search form). So how would I make the 'POST' request when the user selects cancel to bring them back to the original query?

Comment: @Dan: Most search functionality (e.g. Django admin, Google) allows you to pass search parameters in the query string (e.g. http://www.google.com/search?q=django). If you can do that then you can just redirect to the GET version of the search. If not, then you're going to have to store the query somewhere (the session, the database, a coookie, etc.) since you can't pass POST data in a redirect. However, having POST-only search is considered quite user-unfriendly since it can't be bookmarked, etc.